# String rotation and anagram detection

Tags: javascript, string

I'm solving a practice question where my code should accept two arguments`(str1,str2)` and apply rotation on `str1` according to `str2`. After each rotation is applied, the first letter of the rotated string should be added to a new string. After all the rotations, if the new string is an anagram of any substring of the original string, the code should return "YES" otherwise it should return "NO".

For example, if these are the arguments : `("abcde","L 3 R 2 R 4")` The ouput would be YES

Explanation: Here, number of rotations are 3.
After applying first rotation L 3, the string is:
'deabc'. Here, the first character is 'd'
After applying second rotation R 2, the string is:
'bcdea'. Here, the first character is 'b'
After applying third rotation R 4, the string is:
'cdeab'. Here, the first character is 'c'

Thus, after all the rotations the new string will be "dbc" which is an anagram of a sub string of original string "abcde".

```
function anagram(str1,str2){
  var i=0 , j = 2 , temp = [] , final = [] , input = str1;

  while(j<str2.length){
    if(str2[i]==='L'){        //left rotation
      for(let k=input.length-parseInt(str2[j])+1 ; k<input.length ; k++){
        temp.push(input[k]);
        }
        for(let l=0 ; l<input.length-parseInt(str2[j])+1; l++){
          temp.push(input[l]);
          }
          final.push(temp[0]);
      }

    if(str2[i]==='R'){       //right rotation
      for(let m=input.length-parseInt(str2[j]) ; m<input.length; m++){
        temp.push(input[m]);
        }
        for(let n=0 ; n< input.length-parseInt(str2[j]); n++){
          temp.push(input[n]);
          }
          final.push(temp[0]);
      }
    input = temp ;
    temp = [];
    i += 4;
    j += 4;
    }

    var a=0, b=final.length-1 ;                 //anagram detection
    while(b<str1.length){
      if(str1.slice(a,b+1).split('').sort().join('')===final.sort().join('')){
        return "YES"}
      a++;
      b++;
      }
      return "NO";
  }
```

The code only return "NO".How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Your code should work.

I just copy/pasted the provided code into a new file. Calling `anagram("abcde", "L 3 R 2 R 4")` returns `YES`. Make sure to check all the routine stuff:

- Did you save the file?
- If you're running the code from a browser, did you refresh the page? If you did, do you need to clear your cache?
- In general, make sure you're running the latest code: if you put `console.log("TEST");` at the beginning of the function, does it print when you run the code? Debug statements like that are a lifesaver.

I find that "didn't reload the code" is all-too-common of a problem (at least for me)!

Comment: yes but it ONLY works for those arguments. for any other set of arguments it only gives "NO".